# Slash missing in redirecting URL

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

```
Route::get('reviews', 'ReviewController@single')->name('reviews');
```

```
// redirect to the new listing
        return redirect()->route('reviews', [$uri]);
```

I'm trying to redirect the URL when submitted. But for example when I submit `https://example.com/` the URL returns as `https://example.com/reviews?example.net` I want it to be `https://example.com/reviews/example.net` (My site: `https://example.com/`
Submitted URL: `https://example.net/`) How can I do this?  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route should be:

```
Route::get('reviews/{uri}', 'ReviewController@single')->name('reviews');
```

and on controller:

```
$uri = 'https://example.net';
return redirect()->route('reviews', $uri);
```

You can learn about parameters in Laravel route here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Change your route declaration like below

```php
Route::get('reviews/{uri}', 'ReviewController@single')->name('reviews');
```

And in the controller function, you can redirect to `reviews` route by using

```php
public function foo()
{

    ...

    $uri = 'https://example.net';
    return redirect()->route('reviews', $uri);
}
```

Comment: Now it returns ```https://example.com/reviews/%24example.net``` but I want it to return ```https://example.com/reviews/example.net```

Comment: Change `'reviews/${uri}'` to `'reviews/{uri}'`. That `$` should not be there.